# Error using \textohm in a Memoir LaTeX book

Tags: memoir, textcomp

This is the error:

```
./LibroOrange.tex:3961: Package textcomp Error: Symbol \textohm not provided by

(textcomp)                font family bch in TS1 encoding.
(textcomp)                Default family used instead.
```

Comment: The Charter font does not have that particular glyph. You'll have to look for something similar...

Comment: And as always on this site, please provide a minimal example others can copy and test on their system. I have no idea how @campa knew you are using the Charter font.

Comment: @daleif I googled the font family `bch` and gave a quick look to the font table. Never heard of it before `:-)`

Comment: @campa never even noticed `bch`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the warn option of textcomp. It will still replace \textohm by a glyph from another font, but will not give an error message but only a warning in the log:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[warn]{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\textohm blblbl
\end{document}


Package textcomp Warning: Symbol \textohm not provided by
(textcomp)                font family bch in TS1 encoding.
(textcomp)                Default family used instead on input line 78.
```

[image]